# AWS EC2 Instance usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, aws-cli

Can you tell me that, how can I determine how much space that I have used for my applications and for server configurations separately in AWS EC2 instance?

I followed below Amazon guidance links 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-connect-to-instance-linux.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html

It gives me the total usage but I'm unable to find the usage of both separately? Could you kindly please help me out of this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add additional volume to your instance?

It is best to use the application partition on a separate volume than the root volume.

Once logged in to the instance, type:
1. **fdisk -l** (as **root**)
and
2. **df -h**

Comment: Thanks for your input.No I didn't create any additional volumes, when I launched a beanstalk app it automatically created an instance and volume for me. Did you meant this? if not no I didn't create any additional volumes. Also regarding your point create new volumes for our app does this recommended by Amazon? additionally the commands you specified is not answering my original question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is beanstalk, then the volume added to it should be the root volume. In this case, it is not possible to determine the size.

But, if you are using your application in a pre-mentioned path, then the application size can be determined using:

du -sch  
exclude "<" and ">"

Regarding "Also regarding your point create new volumes for our app does this recommended by Amazon?", the answer is "no". It is better to keep the application volume different than the root vol because in case of any disaster or backup, we can restore the volume (from snapshot) at an instant..

let me know if this answered your question.